# How to detect infinite loop exist in linear bounded automata (LBA)?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability

The following theorem from Michael Sipser's book "[Introduction to the Theory of Computation](https://books.google.com/books?id=P3f6CAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)" states:

> $A_{\textrm{LBA}}= \{ \langle M, w \rangle \mid \text{$M$ is an LBA that accepts string $w$} \}$.
>
> THEOREM: $A_{\mathrm{LBA}}$ is decidable.

On the proof part, it states:

> The idea for detecting when $M$ is looping is that as $M$ computes on $w$,
>   it goes from configuration to configuration. If $M$ ever repeats a
>   configuration, it would go on to repeat this configuration over and
>   over again and thus be in a loop.

I do not understand this: 
"If $M$ ever repeats a configuration, it would go on to repeat this configuration over and over again". What if $M$ only repeat one configuration, then halts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The machine $M$ is deterministic. This means that, if $M$ is in a certain configuration $c$, then there is a single fixed configuration $c'$ (determined by the rules of $M$) which the execution of one step will lead it to. If $M$ ever reaches the configuration $c$ again, then the configuration $c'$ will follow no matter what. Hence, if the computation of $M$ causes it to be assume configurations $c_1, \dots, c_n$ and $c_n = c_1$, then $M$ will repeat the loop $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ indefinitely.

Comment: What if we change the $M$ to a normal deterministic turing machine, which is allowed to move off the input portion. if $C_{1}$ = $C_{n}$, does $M$ will repeat the loop too?

Comment: "Configuration" comprises the contents of all tapes of $M$ as well as the positions of every head and $M$'s internal state. Hence, it does not matter.

Comment: If $M$ goes to an infinite loop on $w$, does it mean that : $w$ does not belong to the language which $M$ recognize?

Comment: You should review the definition of Turing-recognizable in Sipser's book. (In the 3rd edition I have here at hand it's Definition 3.5, p.170; see also the discussion in p. 169.). If $M$ accepts $w$, then it must halt in the accept state; if it loops, then it doesn't even halt.

Comment: So, if $M$ does not halt on $w$, then $w$ does not belong to the language of $M$, right?

Comment: That is essentially it.

Comment: then, if I wrote a code piece in Java: `while(true){};`, then run the code in a linux machine and it goes into an infinite loop, May I say that the linux machine(Turing machine) does not recognize the code piece?

Comment: Sorry, but this site isn't designed for back-and-forth interactive assistance. If you have further conceptual difficulties you'd like to ask about, then I suggest doing so in a new question.

Comment: Yes, I did post the question about this, if you have interest, please refer: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/112096/is-the-infinite-program-turing-recognizable-decidable